# XDebug not listed in the output of phpinfo()

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I am trying to enable XDebug so I can use it along with the PHPStorm (I am on Mac) and although I do not have any errors XDebug is not listed in the phpinfo() output. I also tried with XDebug wizard but with the same result. Here are all my configurations:

I modified the `/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php.ini` which I get from:

```
$ php --ini:

Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.2
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini
```

with the following:

```
zend_extension ="/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20170718/xdebug.so"

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

`xdebug.so` was installed with pecl without any errors:

```
$ pecl install xdebug
```

To confirm that I have the `xdebug.so`:

[image]

The output from `php -m` is as follows:

```
[PHP Modules]
ast
bcmath
...
wddx
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Xdebug
Zend OPcache
```

After all this configurations I run:

```
$ sudo apachectl restart
```

But in the output of `phpinfo()` I do not have it enabled:

[image]

I also looked all over the content, but there is nothing connected to `xdebug`.

Should also note that I restarted my local server before the phpinfo() output:

```
$ php bin/console server:start --force
```

My php version (Also you can see that it's showing Xdebug as properly enabled):

```
❯ php -v
PHP 7.2.27 (cli) (built: Jan 24 2020 03:49:45) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.9.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.27, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Can you check the php-fpm directories if there is xdebug enabled? php-cli can have a different configuration set than php-fpm. Can you check the used ini-directories inside your `phpinfo()` which runs inside apache?

Comment: Run a page with `phpinfo()` output **captured via browser** -- your Apache most likely uses different php.ini than CLI environment, therefore checking `php -i` here would be useless/irrelevant. P.S. So what web server do you actually use -- Apache or Symfony one? Apache should use TS builds; Symfony one will be using CLI and can be NTS (just as your info says).

Comment: @LazyOne the path to the php.ini file from the phpinfo() output captured via the browser is exactly the same: /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php.ini

Comment: @vaklinzi I know, you have a Mac and not Windows .. but please try restarting whole computer as it helps sometimes. Right now, if both use the same set of .ini files (I trust you on that) and it uses the same stuff .. it should actually work. If you can and do not mind -- can you post a full header output for both `php -i` as well as `phpinfo()` captured via browser? By "header" I mean before it will start listing the actual settings/modules... Maybe (just maybe) you are somehow missing something there (there is always a chance for this)?

Comment: @vaklinzi Please also check the error log for PHP -- does it write anything there by any chance?

Comment: @LazyOne restarting my Mac fix the problem. Thank you very much for the suggestion. Please make an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @vaklinzi I do not see how should I answer it -- "Reboot your computer"? -- too simple without all the rest stuff that was suggested to check at the same time. Please make your own answer with what you tried and how it was resolved (you can accept your own answers), this will help others in similar situation (to all unbelievers: the "reboot magic" actually works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @LazyOne suggested, I tried rebooting my system and everything started working properly. Looks like something was needing a reboot to start using the new settings/configurations. So if you tried everything and all looks good from configuration point, try rebooting your system.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the pc it's working fine.